# How to ignore time-zone on new Date()?

Tags: javascript, timestamp-with-timezone

I have JavaScript function called `updateLatestDate` that receive as parameter array of objects.

One of the properties of the object in array is the `MeasureDate` property of date type.

The function `updateLatestDate` returns the latest date existing in array.

Here is the function:

```
function updateLatestDate(sensorsData) {
    return new Date(Math.max.apply(null, sensorsData.map(function (e) {
        return new Date(e.MeasureDate);
    })));
}
```

And here is the example of parameter that function receive:

```
[{
    "Address": 54,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2009-11-27T18:10:00",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 26,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "West",
    "MeasureDate": "2010-15-27T15:15:00",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2012-10-27T18:10:00",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  }]
```

The function `updateLatestDate` will return `MeasureDate` value of last object in the array.

And it will look like that:

```
 var latestDate = Sat Oct 27 2012 21:10:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)
```

As you can see the time of the returned result is different from the time of the input object.The time changed according to **GMT**.

But I don't want the time to be changed according to GMT.

The desired result is:

```
 var latestDate = Sat Oct 27 2012 18:10:00
```

Any idea how can I ignore time zone when date returned from updateLatestDate function?

Comment: What do you mean when it look like that ? In your debogguer ? In what the user see ?

Comment: Use moment library it is the best

Comment: @Walfrat yeas in debugger.Later I send the value to the server

Comment: @Devank is the any way to solve this problem without using library?

Comment: @Michael So your input will be "Sat Oct 27 2012 21:10:00 GMT+0300" and output will be "Sat Oct 27 2012 23:40:00"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Frz Khan pointed, you can use the .[toISOString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) function when returning the date from your function, but if you're seeking the UTC format, use the [.toUTCString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp), it would output something like `Mon, 18 Apr 2016 18:09:32 GMT`

```
function updateLatestDate(sensorsData) {
    return new Date(Math.max.apply(null, sensorsData.map(function (e) {
        return new Date(e.MeasureDate).toUTCString();
    })));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Chris. Just a side note. I think you should link to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead of w3schools. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The Date.toISOString() function is what you need
try this:

```
var d = new Date("2012-10-27T18:10:00");
d.toISOString();
```

result:

```
"2012-10-27T18:10:00.000Z"
```

Answer (score -3):

If you use moment it will be

```
moment('Sat Oct 27 2012 21:10:00 GMT+0300', 'ddd MMM DD DDDD HH:mm:SS [GMT]ZZ').format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:SS')
```