# react-native Date not return as converted timezone

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to make Date `without timsezone` converted inside React Native app?

```
new Date('2019-11-15T00:00:00+00:00')
```

It give `2019-11-14T00:00:00.000Z`?

How do I make sure it is 15th?

Comment: Why don't you use `moment.js`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore time-zone on new Date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697020/how-to-ignore-time-zone-on-new-date)

Comment: To bad I cannot assign strng to Nativebase DatePicker defaultDate.

Answer (score 1):

Date:

```
const date = new Date('2019-11-15T00:00:00+00:00');
const date2 = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes());
```

String:

```
const date = new Date('2019-11-15T00:00:00+00:00');
date.toUTCString();
```

Comment: To bad I cannot assign strng to Nativebase DatePicker defaultDate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184747/parse-string-to-date-with-moment-js